# The container object cannot accept the child object associated with the element 'String' because the container is already full

Tags: java

I am trying to build an existing Java application. I added the relevant JAR's and the dependencies and when I try to build the application, I get the below error.

```
environment: fineosenv
configFile: bulkupload_config.xml
Initialise TA Properties
Using System Defined TA Properties File : fineos.properties
  TA properties read from [file:/C:/workspaces/CommBiz_workspace/fineos-orion-8.2.13-CBA-4.2.43/build/classes/fineos.properties] 
> Locating ta.home = C:\workspaces\CommBiz_workspace

org.xml.sax.SAXException: The container object (com.fineos.ta.xmlTypes.castor.PropertytypesChoice) cannot accept the child object associated with the element 'String' because the container is already full!

ValidationException: The container object (com.fineos.ta.xmlTypes.castor.PropertytypesChoice) cannot accept the child object associated with the element 'String' because the container is already full! at org.exolab.castor.xml.UnmarshalHandler.startElement(UnmarshalHandler.java:1711)
at org.exolab.castor.xml.UnmarshalHandler.startElement(UnmarshalHandler.java:1711)
    at org.exolab.castor.xml.UnmarshalHandler.startElement(UnmarshalHandler.java:1375)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
```

I am suspecting it's something to do with XML configuration files? Has anyone come across this error? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
R

Comment: This is an error being thrown by some arbitrary codebase. Without seeing the code, we can't possibly tell you what's wrong, other than to tell you that a `ValidationException` occurred at line 1711 of `UnmarshalHandler.java`, which is exactly what the stack trace literally reads as. Please produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There is an XML element attempting to be placed in an element in the XML document it is parsing
that's DTD or Schema specifies can only have a maximum number of elements or maximum number of elements of a particular type, so it is throwing the error based on the DTD or Schema rules.
It cannot accept another(more) child element in the ≪String> element.